How to Efficiently Find Consecutive Rows with Matching Criteria in SQL?
I have a dataset that tracks user activity, and I need to identify consecutive rows where a specific condition is met. The table structure and sample data are as follows:
Table: UserActivity



UserID
Activity
Timestamp




1
Login
2023-11-01 08:00:00


1
PageView
2023-11-01 08:10:00


1
Login
2023-11-01 08:15:00


1
Logout
2023-11-01 08:20:00


2
Login
2023-11-01 09:00:00


2
Login
2023-11-01 09:05:00


2
PageView
2023-11-01 09:10:00



I want to identify cases where consecutive rows for the same user have the same Activity, along with their timestamps. For example:
For UserID = 2, there are two consecutive Login activities. Like this.
Expected Output



UserID
Activity
StartTimestamp
EndTimestamp




2
Login
2023-11-01 09:00:00
2023-11-01 09:05:00



I have attempted using a self-join to compare each row with the previous one, but it becomes computationally expensive for large datasets. I’ve also tried using LAG and LEAD functions, but I’m struggling to group consecutive rows efficiently.

Which dbms are you actually using, MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Multiple dbms tags is a good way to avoid answers.)

Anyway, same problem can often have several solutions having very different performance costs.

Show us your attempt with LAG. This seems like the most efficient solution. Do you need to handle cases with 3+ duplicates in a row?

I've removed the conflicting tags, please [edit] your question to (re)tag the RDBMS (and ideally the version) you are really using.

I am trying this 'select userid, activity, timestamp,lag(activity) over (partition by userid order by timestamp) as prev_activity
from useractivity;

I am using MySQL 8.0

It looks like you may understand this, but for others who come reading, remember that "consecutive" has no inherent meaning in SQL.  Rows in a table are, by definition, unordered, unless you add an ORDER BY clause.

This may help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188775/selecting-consecutive-rows-with-same-values

Here is a possible solution using LAG. This solution assumes no more then 2 duplicates per UserID+Activity.
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT UserID, Activity, 
        LAG(USERID) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp)  as PrevID, 
        LAG(Activity) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp)  as PrevActivity, 
        LAG(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp)  as StartTimeStamp, 
        TimeStamp as EndTimeStamp
FROM Example
ORDER BY TimeStamp
)
SELECT UserID, Activity, StartTimeStamp, EndTimeStamp
FROM CTE
WHERE UserID=PrevID AND Activity=PrevActivity
ORDER BY StartTimeStamp

fiddle



UserID
Activity
StartTimeStamp
EndTimeStamp




2
Login
2023-11-01 09:00:00
2023-11-01 09:05:00




Will miss double duplicates etc., see sample data adjusted fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/luOIW475

I agree. this solution only works for the limited example provided by walkingbas. To handle a wider variety of examples I suggest trying one of the other answers provided for this question.

Alternate solution adapting strategy from stackexchange user tombom
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188775/selecting-consecutive-rows-with-same-values
This solution handles 2+ duplicates per UserID+Activity in a row.
SELECT userID, 
       Activity, 
       MIN(Timestamp) as starttime,
       MAX(Timestamp) as endtime
FROM (
    SELECT
    t.*
    , @groupNumber := IF(@prev_userID != userID OR @prev_Activity != Activity, @groupNumber + 1, @groupNumber) AS gn
    , @prev_userID := userID
    , @prev_Activity := Activity
    FROM Example t
    , (SELECT @groupNumber := 0, @prev_userID := NULL, @prev_Activity := NULL) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY userID, Timestamp
) sq
GROUP BY gn, userID, Activity
HAVING Count(*) > 1 

fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/cNbjWMcz

@jarlh thanks for the additional examples. Do you see any issues with this solution?

Seems to work as desired. (That's why I upvoted it.)

@jarlh Thanks. I wish there was a way to know who upvoted an answer.

Probably so users don't feel obligated to return upvotes.

And I wish it would be forbidden to downvote without a comment to explain the reason. But there are good reasons why things are as they are ;)
